# How does a Jogi lead his life? Are "Yogi" and "Jogi" the same?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, yoga, sanyasi

How does or How should a Jogi lead his or her live? Bhogi is voracious, rogi lives in travail and yogi is ascetic. Are both 'yogi' and 'jogi' the same?

Comment: I think jogi is the pronunciation of yogi in awadhi or bhind dialect.

Comment: Both are some. Jogi is the vikruthi form of Yogi.

Comment: What is vikruthi of yogi? if yogi has vikruthi, he is not yogi at all. I think scriptures may have some explanations.

Comment: Jogi and Yogi are  the same..So u are basically asking **How does a Yogi live?**

Comment: Yes, how does they live? any specific charecteristics? In jyotish , after watching kundalis, they say -  you will live life of jogi. So how do they live?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Jogi` is an अपभ्रंश (*[apabhramsha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apabhramsha)*) of `Yogi`. Like, how it's "Jamuna" for "Yamuna", "Jam" for "Yam", "Jashoda" for "Yashoda" & "JAdava" for "YAdava". So both are same.

**Yogi means a person, who is in Yoga**. Early reference to Yoga in Gita is:

> BG 2.53 -
>   श्रुतिविप्रतिपन्ना ते यदा स्थास्यति निश्चला।
>   **समाधावचला** बुद्धिस्तदा **योगमवाप्स्यसि**।
>   You are diverted (bewildered/mistaken) with *Sruti*-s (*Veda*-s). Remaining unshakable, when *Buddhi*(consciousness) becomes immutable into *SamAdhi*(intenseness or union), then you will attain **yoga** (union).

Note that, *SamAdhi* & *Yoga* are kind of synonymous in most of the translations.

After this, Arjuna asks same question as yours, i.e. "How does Jogi live?":
<sub>(All are from Gambhirananda's translation from below)</sub>

> BG 2.54 -
>   स्थितप्रज्ञस्य का भाषा **समाधिस्थस्य** केशव।
>   स्थितधीः किं प्रभाषेत किमासीत व्रजेत किम्
>   Arjuna said O kesava, **what is the description** of a man of steady wisdom who is Self-absorbed? How does the man of steady wisdom speak? How does he sit? How does he move about?

Here goes your answer:

> BG 2.55, 2.56, 2.57, 2.58 - The Blessed said O Partha, when one fully **renounces all the desires** that have entered the mind, and remains **satisfied in the Self** alone by the Self, then he is called a man of steady wisdom. That monk is called a man of steady wisdom when his **mind is unperturbed in sorrow, he is free from longing for delights**, and has gone beyond attachment, fear and anger. The wisdom of that person remains established who has **no attachments** for anything anywhere, who **neither welcomes nor rejects anything whatever good or bad** when he comes across it.And when this one fully withdraws the senses from the objects of the senses, as a tortoise wholly (withdraws) the limbs, then his wisdom remains established. ...

Answer (score 1):

#### How should a Yogi (a.k.a Jogi, Yati) lead his live?

**TLDR** (from [MB 12.240](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b067.htm)):

- **Objective**: Unite intellect, mind, the senses, and the all-pervading soul to obtain the knowledge of foremost kind
- **Who can take up yoga**: man or woman belonging to any varṇa (caste)
- **Residence**: caves, temples, empty houses or apartments but don't stay too long at any one place; imitate the wind: asangah - unattached to all things
- **Disposition to things and other beings**

  - Show uniform behaviour toward all beings - a Brahmin (learned one), a cow (sacred), a dog (detestable) or an outcaste (who eats dog-meat). [[BG 5.18](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=18&etgb=1&setgb=1)]
  - React in the same manner if one praises or criticizes.
  - View with an equal eye: a piece of stone or a lump of gold.
- **What to do and How to practice**

  - Restraining all the senses within the heart, one should concentrate on the Eternal and the Indestructible like a man of the world thinks of wealth and other valuable possessions.
  - One should practise Yoga after dusk, before dawn, and at dawn of day, seated on a mountain summit, or at the foot of a large tree.
  - Abandon the 5 impediments of Yoga viz., desire (by giving up all purposes), wrath (by tranquillity of disposition), cupidity, fear, and sleep.

---

---

#### What does the word *Yogi* mean anyway?

The Sanskrit root word for Yoga or Yogi is Yuj (युज्). Here are some [meanings](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/AP90Scan/2014/web/webtc/servepdf.php?page=0894) of Yuj (युज्):

> 1. To join, unite, attach, connect, add; तमर्थमिव भारत्या सुतया **योक्तुमर्हसि** ([Ku. 6.79](https://archive.org/stream/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes-MrKale1917#page/n248/mode/1up)); रविपीत जला तपात्यये पुनरोघेन हि **युज्यते** नदी ([Ku 4.44](https://archive.org/stream/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes-MrKale1917#page/n228/mode/1up))
> 2. To turn or direct towards; पापान्निवारयति **योजयते** हिताय ([Bh. 2.72](http://stotram.lalitaalaalitah.com/2011/11/neeti-shatakam-of-bharthruhari.html))
> 3. To concentrate one's attention upon; मनः संयम्य मच्चित्तो **युक्त** आसीत मत्परः ([BG 6.14](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/6/13-14)); **युञ्जन्नेवं** सदात्मानं ([BG 6.15](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?etgb=1&setgb=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=6&field_nsutra_value=14))
> 4. To be intent on, be absorbed in, be directed towards; दैवकर्मणि **युक्तो** हि बिभर्तीदं चराचरम् (Manu [3.75](https://archive.org/stream/ManuSmriti_201601/Manu-Smriti#page/n45/mode/1up))

And of word [Yoga](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/AP90Scan/2014/web/webtc/servepdf.php?page=0896) (योगः):

> Deep and abstract meditation, concentration of the mind, contemplation of 
>   the Supreme Spirit, which in Yoga phil. is defined as चित्तवृत्तिनिरोध; सती सती योगविसृष्टदेहा ([Ku. 1.21](https://archive.org/stream/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes/KumarasambhavaCantosI-vii-SanskritCommentaryEnglishTranslationNotes-MrKale1917#page/n204/mode/1up)); योगेनांते तनुत्यजां ([R. 1.8](https://archive.org/stream/raghuvamsaofkali00kliduoft#page/n298/mode/1up)).

---

#### Vyāsa Explains a Yogi's Objectives and Lifestyle

In Śānti-parva of Mahābhārata, Śuka [asks](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b066.htm) his father, Vyāsa:

> Tell me by what means is Brahma to be apprehended?
>
> Is it by penance, by Brahmacharya, by renunciation of everything, by intelligence, by the aid of the Sankhya philosophy, or by **Yoga**?
>
> By what means may what kind of singleness of purpose be attained by men, with respect to both, viz., the mind and the senses?

Then Vyāsa [explains](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b067.htm) the following.

> Listen now to me as I expound to thee all that should be done (for the same end) according to the Yoga doctrine.
>
> The uniting together of Intellect and Mind, and all the Senses, and the all-pervading Soul is said to be Knowledge of the foremost kind. That Knowledge should be acquired (through the preceptor's aid) by one that is of a tranquil disposition, that has mastered his senses, that is capable (by meditation) of turning his gaze on the Soul, that takes a pleasure in (such) meditation, that is endued with intelligence and pure in acts.
>
> One should seek to acquire this Knowledge by abandoning those five
>   impediments of Yoga which are known to the wise, viz., desire, wrath,
>   cupidity, fear, and sleep. Wrath is conquered by tranquillity of
>   disposition. Desire is conquered by giving up all purposes. By
>   reflecting with the aid of the understanding upon topics worthy of
>   reflection, one endued with patience succeeds in abandoning sleep. By
>   steady endurance one should restrain one's organs of generation and
>   the stomach (from unworthy or sinful indulgence). One should protect
>   one's hands and feet by (using) one's eyes. One should protect one's
>   eyes and ears by the aid of one's mind, one's mind and speech by one's
>   acts. One should avoid fear by heedfulness, and pride by waiting upon
>   the wise. Subduing procrastination, one should, by these means, subdue
>   these impediments of Yoga. One should pay one's adorations to fire and
>   the Brahmanas, and one should bow one's head to the deities. One
>   should avoid all kinds of inauspicious discourse, and speech that is
>   fraught with malice, and words that are painful to other minds.
>
> Brahma is the effulgent seed (of everything). It is, again, the
>   essence of that seed whence is all this. Brahma became the eye, in the
>   form of this mobile and immobile universe, of all entities that took
>   birth.
>
> **Meditation, study, gift, truth, modesty, simplicity, forgiveness,
>   purity of body, purity of conduct, subjugation of the senses, these
>   enhance one's energy, which (when enhanced) destroys one's sins.** By
>   behaving equally towards all creatures and by living in contentment
>   upon what is acquired easily and without effort, one attains to the
>   fruition of all one's objects and succeeds in obtaining knowledge.
>   Cleansed of all sins, endued with energy, abstemious in diet, with
>   senses under complete control, one should, after having subdued both
>   desire and wrath, seek to attain to Brahma, Firmly uniting the senses
>   and the mind (having drawn them away from all external objects) with
>   gaze fixed inwards, one should, in the still hours of evening or in
>   those before dawn, place one's mind upon the knowledge.
>
> If even one of the five senses of a human being be kept unrestrained,
>   all his wisdom may be seen to escape through it like water through an
>   unstopped hole at the bottom of a leathern bag. The mind in the first
>   instance should be sought to be restrained by the Yogin after the
>   manner of a fisherman seeking at the outset to render that one among
>   the fish powerless from which there is the greatest danger to his
>   nets.
>
> Having first subdued the mind, the Yogin should then proceed to subdue
>   his ears, then his eyes, then his tongue, and then his nose. Having
>   restrained these, he should fix them on the mind. **Then withdrawing the
>   mind from all purposes, he should fix it on the knowledge. Indeed,
>   having restrained the five senses, the Yati should fix them on the
>   mind. When these the mind for their sixth become concentrated in the
>   knowledge, and thus concentrated remain steady and untroubled, then
>   Brahma becomes perceptible like a smokeless fire of blazing flames or
>   the Sun of effulgent radiance.** Indeed, one then beholds in oneself
>   one's soul like lightning fire in the skies. Everything then appears
>   in it and it appears in everything in consequence of its infinitude.
>   Those high-souled Brahmanas that are possessed of wisdom, that are
>   endued with fortitude, that are possessed of high knowledge, and that
>   are engaged in the good of all creatures, succeed in beholding it.
>
> Engaged in the observance of austere vows, the Yogin who conducts
>   himself thus for six months, seated by himself on an isolated spot,
>   succeeds in attaining to an equality with the Indestructible.
>   Annihilation, extension, power to present varied aspects in the same
>   person or body, celestial scents, and sounds, and sights, the most
>   agreeable sensations of taste and touch, pleasurable sensations of
>   coolness and warmth, equality with the wind, capability of
>   understanding (by inward light) the meaning of scriptures and every
>   work of genius, companionship of celestial damsels,--acquiring all
>   these by Yoga the Yogin should disregard them and merge them all in
>   the knowledge. Restraining speech and the senses one should practise
>   Yoga during the hours after dusk, the hours before dawn, and at dawn
>   of day, seated on a mountain summit, or at the foot of a goodly tree,
>   or with a tree before him. Restraining all the senses within the
>   heart, one should, with faculties concentrated, think on the Eternal
>   and Indestructible like a man of the world thinking of wealth and
>   other valuable possessions. One should never, while practising Yoga,
>   withdraw one's mind from it.
>
> One should with devotion betake oneself to those means by which one
>   may succeed in restraining the mind that is very restless. One should
>   never permit oneself to fall away from it. With the senses and the
>   mind withdrawn from everything else, the Yogin (for practice) should
>   betake himself to empty caves of mountains, to temples consecrated to
>   the deities, and to empty houses or apartments, for living there. One
>   should not associate with another in either speech, act, or thought.
>   Disregarding all things, and eating very abstemiously, the Yogin
>   should look with an equal eye upon objects acquired or lost. **He should
>   behave after the same manner towards one that praises and one that
>   censures him. He should not seek the good or the evil of one or the
>   other. He should not rejoice at an acquisition or suffer anxiety when
>   he meets with failure or loss. Of uniform behaviour towards all
>   beings, he should imitate the wind.** Unto one whose mind is thus turned
>   to itself, who leads a life of purity, and who casts an equal eye upon
>   all things,--indeed, unto one who is ever engaged in Yoga thus for
>   even six months,--Brahma as represented by sound appears very vividly.
>   Beholding all men afflicted with anxiety (on account of earning wealth
>   and comfort), the Yogin should view a clod of earth, a piece of stone,
>   and a lump of gold with an equal eye. Indeed, he should withdraw
>   himself from this path (of earning wealth), cherishing an aversion for
>   it, and never suffer himself to be stupefied.
>
> **Even if a person happens to belong to the inferior order, even if one
>   happens to be a woman, both of them, by following in the track
>   indicated above, will surely attain to the highest end.** He that has
>   subdued his mind beholds in his own self, by the aid of his own
>   knowledge the Uncreate, Ancient, Undeteriorating, and Eternal
>   Brahma,--That, viz., which can not be attained to except by fixed
>   senses,--That which is subtiler than the most subtile, and grosser
>   than the most gross, and which is Emancipation's self.

Comment: Nice summary. I think last section can be reduced to make it more readable.

Comment: @iammilind Yeah, I thought of trimming it a bit but since I provided a summary left the whole thing as is.